# ¿Como registro nuevos usuarios teniendo una cuenta ya iniciada con laravel?

Tags: laravel

He creado el login y registro utilizando **make:auth** de Laravel 5.8 y va todo correcto, pero necesito que solo el administrador pueda añadir nuevos usuarios.

Ya pude hacer que solo el administrador pueda ingresar a la ruta de la pagina de registro que he creado, pero cuando ingreso al navegador para registrar un nuevo usuario y le doy clic a "registrar", me regresa a la pagina de inicio sin añadir el nuevo usuario a la base de datos.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Básicamente, copie el mismo formulario que trae make:auth, por lo que no se porque no registra nuevos usuarios.

Comment: Se podría hacer modificando el controlador, pero no creo que sea buena idea usar el mismo controlador que Laravel crea para que un usuario se autoregistre, para lo que tu quieres, que es que el usuario administrador agregue nuevos usuarios. Sería mejor que crees tu propio controlador con la lógica típica de un CRUD

Comment: porloscerros, creo que haré lo que me indica Alexander Rodriguez, de todas formas intentaré hacer lo que me recomiendas.   Soy nuevo en PHP y Laravel y si hago un CRUD desde 0, no sabría como usar el md5 que utiliza laravel para el campo de la contraseña.

Comment: Ok Alex, no hay problema, fué solo una sugerencia. Para escribir una respuesta, solo me faltaría saber como haces para "que solo el administrador pueda ingresar a la ruta de la pagina de registro". Si lo que te detiene es como encriptar la contraseña, laravel te lo hace fácil con `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make($request->password);`

Answer (score 1):

Como estas usando el sistema de autentificacion basica de Laravel, este tiene un **middleware** que evita acceder a la vista: **register.blade.php** cuando esta logueado por un usuario.

Para solucionar este problema debes modificar el siguiente archivo controlador:

Abre el archivo controlador llamado: **RegisterController.php** el cual esta ubicado en la ruta: **app/Http/Controllers/Auth**

y comenta el codigo que llama el middleware: $this->middleware('guest'); ubicado en el metodo __construct()

```
public function __construct()
{
   // $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

Haciendo esto ya te permitira acceder al registro en cualquier momento y crear nuevos usuarios aun estando legueado.